# JS - Repeat array items n times on n position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have entered the array in the format :

```
let in = [{name: "Milos", repeat: null},{name: "Milos1", repeat: 2},{name: "Milos2", repeat: null},{name: "Milos3", repeat: 4}, .... ];
```

What is key here, the key is the `repeat` property.

What that means,

If any item in the array has `repeat` property, that item must be repeatable in the array,  which means, will be placed in position `n`, with `n` repeat times, array what is expected as result is :

```
let out = [
{name: "Milos", repeat: null},
{name: "Milos1", repeat: 2},
{name: "Milos2", repeat: null},
{name: "Milos1", repeat: 2},
{name: "Milos3", repeat: 4}, ...., 
{name: "Milos1", repeat: 2}, ...  
{name: "Milos3", repeat: 4}, ..., 
{name: "Milos1", repeat: 2}, ... 
{name: "Milos3", repeat: 4}, ...];
```

**Note: Dots means items with `repeat` property `null`.**

Limitation, I don't want to expand the array is there no more space for that.

Comment: Your attempts to solve your task are missing

Comment: I don't really understand how the repeats are expanded. Why is the result `0,1,2,1,3,1` rather than `0,1,1,1,2,3`?

Comment: I currently work on that, old tries are deleted. I'll post a new one soon.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, because ``Milos2`` will be repeated on every 2nd (or even) position, repeat is 2, ``Milos3`` will be repeated on every 4th position, etc...

Comment: what if the repeats overwrite each other?